# NestJS: How to get instance of mongoose for health check?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am using the @nestjs/mongoose package to connect to Mongo DB. I have this in app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
   MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      bufferCommands: false,
      bufferMaxEntries: 0,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
})]
```

Now, the NestJS service is running in a Kubernetes cluster with proper health, liveness and readiness checks. Whenever the readiness or health end-point is invoked on the service, i need to check if the hosted Atlas Mongo DB connection is available or if there is an outage. As of now, the following code is executed for readiness and health end-points:

```
this.mongoDbConnection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, options);
return (this.mongoDbConnection.connection.readyState === 1);
```

But this creates a new connection with the mongo DB server. What i want is to retrieve the readyState of the existing connection that NestJS makes through MongooseModule.forRoot in app.module.ts.

I am not sure how to retrieve the existing mongoose connection object in the health check service code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest using @nestjs/terminus module, see the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus) and/or [repository](https://github.com/nestjs/terminus) to integrate the module in application.

and your health controller can look something like this

```js
import { Controller, Get } from "@nestjs/common";
import {
  HealthCheck,
  HealthCheckResult,
  HealthCheckService,
  MongooseHealthIndicator,
} from "@nestjs/terminus";

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {

  constructor(
    private healthCheck: HealthCheckService,
    private mongooseHealth: MongooseHealthIndicator,
  ) {
  }

  @Get()
  @HealthCheck()
  async check(): Promise<HealthCheckResult> {
    return this.healthCheck.check(
      [
        () => this.mongooseHealth.pingCheck("mongoDB"),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try remove this line

```
useUnifiedTopology: true
```

**UPDATE:**

I apologize for my answer. My project create health check route for K8s  like this

```
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';

@Controller()
export class HealthzController {
  constructor (@InjectConnection() private readonly connection: Connection) { }

  @Get('/_status/healthz')
  healthCheck (@Res() res: Response) {
    if (this.connection.readyState === 1) {
      res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ db: { status: 'up' } });
    } else {
      res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ db: { status: 'down' } });
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks for your reply but this option has no effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

mongoose will be available globally it will handle this for you (the pools number by default):

on any file on the node thread you can import the mongoose and read the state

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
```

> Note: 
>   if you called it directly without any asynchronous function it will return 0 state if its wrapped on other function state it will work as charm

Comment: i tried this but i am getting 0 as you said. I didn't get what you mean by "if its wrapped on other function state it will work as charm"

Comment: try `setTimeout(()=>{console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);},5000)`

Comment: and what I meant to be wrapped by another function I ment it's called later after the mongoose establishes the connection, but now you are getting `0` it executed before the connection has been established.

Comment: it's not working, i am calling the health check every 60 seconds so even if readyState returned 0 the first time, it should have returned 1 the next time but it doesn't.

Comment: if i run the following code before console.log, readyState works fine: `this.mongoDbConnection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, options);`  so the global handler works fine if i create another mongoose connection in the same file but doesn't work for NestJS's automation connection.

Comment: did you tried to listen to the events `connection.on('disconnected', (e) => { console.log('-> lost connection'); updateConnectionStatus(e) });`  and you can use it with defferant events , see the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201333/discussion-between-eslam-abu-hugair-and-ramandeep-singh).

Comment: If this issue was resolved in the chat (which is not available anymore) it would be good to update this Q&A with any results since as it stands, there isn't a resolution here.

I currently ignore readyState and just attempt a db write into small capped collection. If the write succeeds http status = 200, otherwise 500